# Allow entry of only once till year.?

Tags: php, sql

Well i have a form in site where people submit domains to my database, but whats the problem that they can add 1 domain many times which means the archive becomes a kind of useless
I wanted to refrain the query to check the date of submission of previous domain from db and check if it submitted last year or in the same year.

So what i mean is allow entry of a domain in db once a year and after one year it can be re submitted..
Any help would be appreciated ..

My try for query

```
 $total_year = 24*60*60*5;
 $timev = time();
 $control_domains = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM domains WHERE url LIKE '%$url%' AND $timev - time < $total_year");
```

Comment: Can you please code in english, so at least we understand what your column mean and each variable means, else it's really hard to help you

Comment: We could also do with seeing the database structure. `time()` will give you a time in seconds, and comparing that directly with a mysql datetime field won't work.

Comment: Also, http://bobby-tables.com/ - Read about SQL injection. (I'm assuming `$ara` is supplied by your users)

Comment: add a unique index on domain and year.

Comment: @Crontab the supplied variable is already filtered above the code (not here)

Comment: @andrewsi so what is the alternative?

Comment: @RojerTenison I find it a lot easier to do comparisons if I use `time()` everywhere - you can just compare one number directly with another. It means you need to convert the number with `date()` when you want to output it nicely, but that's a small price to pay, especially for a field that's just designed to be used for admin.

Comment: @andrewsi so instead of using time() i shall use date() but what about the comparative number im gonna use , to compare it with? i mean to total it to 1 year?

Comment: Have a look at the manual page for mysql date comparison: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html - `CURTIME()` gives you the current time, and you can use that when you insert something to the database; and `ADDDATE()` lets you add to a date, so you can check the value when you're doing your comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM domains WHERE url LIKE '%$url%' AND time < date_sub(now(),interval 365 DAY);
```

This selects all domains older than 365 days (1 year). If you want all domains in the last year, reverse the < sign (so it will become >).
(I assumed the column where your time or date is stored is called time). You might need to change it a bit.

My suggestion is that you store a DATE or DATETIME.